# Rails test with Capybara check if attribute of an element present or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I need to find weather no-follow link exists in external email and it should not be in any internal email.

```
test "should have nofollow in external links and not in internal links in comment" do
  visit @game_path
  fill_in('comment_comment', :with => 'Please click link <a href='http://www.internallink.com/soccer'> internal link <a/> and click external link <a href='http://www.google.com'> external link <a/>
  click_button('submit_comment')
  assert page.has_no_css?('div.error'), "Error div found on page after posting comment"
  assert page.has_content?('Please click link '), "Comment not found on page after posting"
  ext = find(:xpath, "//a[@href='http://www.google.com']")
  assert_equal(ext['rel'], "nofollow") 
  internal = find(:xpath, "//a[@href='http://www.internallink.com/soccer']")
  assert_equal(internal.try(:rel), nil)
end
```

It is giving error in `assert_equal(int.try(:rel), nil)`. Can anybuddy guide me for solution?

**My final goal is to test in User comment,  External link should have  rel='nofollow' attribute present or not?**

Comment: what is the error it's giving?

Comment: @dax error is NoMethodError: undefined method `rel' for #<Capybara::Element tag="a">

Comment: this might help make things easier?  http://samuelmullen.com/2011/12/use-capybara-add_selector-to-simplify-finding-link/

Comment: Sorry dax, I  didn't find solution there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check for the presence of the link without the rel='nofollow'?

```
find(:xpath, "//a[@href='http://www.internallink.com/soccer' and @rel != 'nofollow']")
```